# Match when pivoting longer

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have the following dataset and I want to pivot part_c_name_1 and part_c_name_2 by one side and then, harvest_1 and harvest_2. When I try to do this with pivot_longer it does not understand that harvest_1 corresponds to part_c_name_1 and harvest_2 to part_c_name_2. The key would be the 1, 2, ... How can I achieve this with pivot_longer?

```
df <- tibble::tribble(    ~ hhid,   ~ part_c_name_1,    ~ part_c_name_2,   ~ harvest_1, ~ harvest_2,
              1010101004,         "Sorghum",        "Groundnut",        81.154,     5.952026,
              1010101007,       "Groundnut", "Cassava (tubers)",   128.1999969,            0)
```

My desirable output would be:

```
df_expected <- tibble::tribble(    ~ hhid,   ~ part_c_name,            ~ name,    ~harvest, ~harvest_value,
                1010101004, "part_c_name_1",         "Sorghum", "harvest_1",         81.154,
                1010101007, "part_c_name_1",       "Groundnut", "harvest_1",    128.1999969,
                1010101004, "part_c_name_2",       "Groundnut", "harvest_2",       5.952026,
                1010101007, "part_c_name_2","Cassava (tubers)", "harvest_2",              0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to do a pivot longer with collapsed names, then separate the names:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-hhid, 
          names_to = c(".value", "value"), names_pattern = "([^_]+)_(\\d+$)", 
          cols_vary = "slowest", 
          names_transform = list(value=~map_chr(.x,
                    ~str_c(str_subset(names(df), .x), collapse = ":"))))%>%
  separate(value, c("part_c_name", "harvest_name"), ":")

# A tibble: 4 × 5
        hhid part_c_name   harvest_name name             harvest
       <dbl> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>              <dbl>
1 1010101004 part_c_name_1 harvest_1    Sorghum            81.2 
2 1010101007 part_c_name_1 harvest_1    Groundnut         128.  
3 1010101004 part_c_name_2 harvest_2    Groundnut           5.95
4 1010101007 part_c_name_2 harvest_2    Cassava (tubers)    0
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to split the original data frame into two, pivot each longer and then left join.

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dfh <- 
  df |> 
  select(-starts_with("part")) |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("harvest"), names_to = "harvest", values_to = "harvest_value") |> 
  mutate(id = stringr::str_sub(harvest, -1))

  df |> 
  select(-starts_with("harvest")) |> 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("part"), names_to = "part_c_name", values_to = "name") |> 
  mutate(id = stringr::str_sub(part_c_name, -1)) |> 
    left_join(dfh, by = c("hhid", "id")) |> 
    select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>         hhid part_c_name   name             harvest   harvest_value
#>        <dbl> <chr>         <chr>            <chr>             <dbl>
#> 1 1010101004 part_c_name_1 Sorghum          harvest_1         81.2 
#> 2 1010101004 part_c_name_2 Groundnut        harvest_2          5.95
#> 3 1010101007 part_c_name_1 Groundnut        harvest_1        128.  
#> 4 1010101007 part_c_name_2 Cassava (tubers) harvest_2          0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>